# How do I show that the reparametrization of a pre-geodesic is pre-geodesic?

Tags: differential-geometry

So this is probably a very silly question but I need to prove the reparametrization of a pre-geodesic is a pre-geodesic. The hint in my book says it's obvious, so I am clearly missing something.

Comment: What is your definition of a pre-geodesic?

Comment: @JackLee "A (regular) curve γ with nowhere vanishing curvature on a surface S is called pre-geodesic on S if some reparametrization of γ is a geodesic on S."

Comment: So a reparametrization of a reparametrization is...

Comment: @JackLee The original parametrization? I'm honestly not sure what it means to reparametrize

Comment: OK, so your first task is to learn the definitions!

Comment: @JackLee Ok so if I understand this correctly, reparametrization is just basically just changing the variable (from t to let's say s). Therefore if I reparametrize a curve that has already been reparametrized, then I should get back to the reparametrization I was trying to reparametrize, just with a different variable?